# Why does Dart StreamController.addStream not work expectedly when joining streams

Tags: dart, dart-async

Given the following Dart code snippet:

```dart
Stream stream1 = new Stream.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (n) => n)
                           .take(10)
                           .asBroadcastStream();
stream1.listen((n) => print("stream1 : $n"),
               onError : (err) => print("stream1 : $err"),
               onDone : () => print("stream1 : done"),
               cancelOnError : false);

Stream stream2 = stream1.where((n) => n % 2 == 0).take(2);
stream2.listen((n) => print("stream2 : $n"),
               onError : (err) => print("stream2 : $err"),
               onDone : () => print("stream2 : done"),
               cancelOnError : false);

Stream stream3 = stream1.where((n) => n % 2 != 0).take(2);
stream3.listen((n) => print("stream3 : $n"),
               onError : (err) => print("stream3 : $err"),
               onDone : () => print("stream3 : done"),
               cancelOnError : false);

StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
controller.addStream(stream2)
  .then((_) => controller.addStream(stream3));
controller.stream.listen((n) => print("composite stream : $n"),
                         onError : (err) => print("composite stream : $err"),
                         onDone : () => print("composite stream : done"),
                         cancelOnError : false);
```

I get the following output:

```
stream1 : 0
stream2 : 0
composite stream : 0
stream1 : 1
stream3 : 1
composite stream : 1
stream1 : 2
stream1 : 3
stream1 : 4
stream1 : 5
stream1 : 6
stream1 : 7
stream1 : 8
stream1 : 9
stream1 : done
stream2 : done
stream3 : done
```

There are a couple of things I don't understand from this output:

1. why is there only one entry each for `stream2` and `stream3` when there should be 2 of each? does the composite stream I created with the `StreamController` consume one of the events from `stream2` and `stream3`? This behaviour seems odd to me, am I missing something?
2. why does `stream2` and `stream3` only complete when `stream1` complete? this is not the natural behaviour I'd expect when both are bounded, and contradicts with the behaviour of `.take(10)` on `stream1`. If I remove the `.take(10)` on `stream1` then `stream2` and `stream3` in fact never completes.

If I modify `controller` to also add the source `stream1` (see snippet and output below), then the `stream2` and `stream3` in fact completes at their natural positions when their 2 elements are up, but I then also get an exception because it tried to listen to one of the streams twice.

```
StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
controller.addStream(stream1)
  .then((_) => controller.addStream(stream2))
  .then((_) => controller.addStream(stream3));
controller.stream.listen((n) => print("composite stream : $n"),
                         onError : (err) => print("composite stream : $err"),
                         onDone : () => print("composite stream : done"),
                         cancelOnError : false);

stream1 : 0
stream2 : 0
composite stream : 0
stream1 : 1
stream3 : 1
composite stream : 1
stream1 : 2
stream2 : 2
stream2 : done
composite stream : 2
stream1 : 3
stream3 : 3
stream3 : done
composite stream : 3
stream1 : 4
composite stream : 4
stream1 : 5
composite stream : 5
stream1 : 6
composite stream : 6
stream1 : 7
composite stream : 7
stream1 : 8
composite stream : 8
stream1 : 9
stream1 : done
composite stream : 9
Uncaught Error: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
Stack Trace:
#0      _StreamController._subscribe (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:151:7)
#1      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:259:157)
#2      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:260:58)
#3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:53:43)
#4      _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:35:16)
#5      _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:32:31)
#6      _AsBroadcastStream.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:466:37)
#7      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:53:43)
#8      _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:35:16)
#9      _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:32:31)
#10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:53:43)
#11     _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:35:16)
#12     _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:32:31)
#13     _AddStreamState._AddStreamState (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:300:133)
#14     _BroadcastStreamController.addStream (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:140:27)
#15     main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/SourceCode/personal/SteamTest/lib/streamtest.dart:38:38)
#16     _ThenFuture._zonedSendValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:371:24)
#17     _TransformFuture._sendValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:348:48)
#18     _ZoneBase._runInZone (dart:async/zone.dart:82:17)
#19     _ZoneBase._runUnguarded (dart:async/zone.dart:102:22)
#20     _ZoneBase.executeCallback (dart:async/zone.dart:58:23)
#21     _TransformFuture._sendValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:348:26)
#22     _FutureImpl._setValueUnchecked (dart:async/future_impl.dart:184:26)
#23     _FutureImpl._asyncSetValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:218:25)
#24     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/event_loop.dart:9:15)
#25     _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:8:13)
#26     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:95:21)
#27     _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (timer_impl.dart:111:23)
#28     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:81:92)


Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
#0      _DefaultZone.handleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:146:7)
#1      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/event_loop.dart:9:15)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/event_loop.dart:13:7)
#3      _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:8:13)
#4      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:95:21)
#5      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:103:7)
#6      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:103:7)
#7      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (timer_impl.dart:111:23)
#8      _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:81:92)
```

Can someone help me make sense of what is going on here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

After debugging the dart code for your example, It seems to me this is a bug.

The take call generates a Take-stream that has a reference to a Where-stream that has a reference to the broadcastStream stream1. By the way, because stream1 is a broadcastStream, this also holds for the Where- and Take-stream (checked during debugging).

The counter for the number of events is a state variable of the Take-stream, but each time you subscribe to the Take-Stream (by calling listen), this creates a subscription to the Where-stream which in turns creates a subscription to stream1. In this case you have 2 subscriptions to stream2 (1 via listen, 1 via the controller) resulting in two 2 subscriptions to stream1 (so 4 in total because of stream3 but this is not important for the discussion).

As a consequence, when stream1 fires event 0, it passes twice through the Take-stream in stream2 decreasing the counter of the Take-stream twice and causing the onDone-event to pass to the second subscription only. Because the counter is decreased by 2 and it is a state variable of the Take-stream, the Take-Stream will not fire anymore when stream1 fires event 2.

So this looks like a bug to me. Two observations.

1. Should the take-stream counter be a state variable in the subscription to the take-stream instead of the take-stream itself?
2. Should every subscription to the Take-Stream result in a new subscription to the source stream? (see also ForwardingStream in the Dart code). This might depend on the broadcast-context.

Maybe they should have a further look at the Rx-code.

Comment: In the Rx .net code (see also RxJS), or RxJava, the subscriptions are kept clean from state variables. The counter logic is added to the original onData/onError/onDone handlers (or Observer) by wrapping the original handlers (via closures: Rx .net,  wrapper class: RxJava)

Comment: I believe this bug has been fixed now. The counter should indeed be on the subscription.